# How to handle WPF Datagrid double click without using code behind

Tags: wpf, mvvm, datagrid, mouseevent, wpftoolkit

We're using Views and ViewModels in this project, and as a result we're trying to have as little in the code-behind for the View as possible.

I'm trying to tie the `MouseDoubleClick` event for a WPFToolkit `DataGrid` to the same code that a `Button` in the same view already is using.

The `Button` is declared as the following:

```
<Button Content="Select" cmd:ButtonBaseExtensions.Command="{Binding CommandViewEmployer}"/>
```

which means it runs the `CommandViewEmployer` Property in the ViewModel. How do I get the `Grid` `MouseDoubleClick` to run the same property? I've tried adding `MouseDoubleClick="{Binding CommandViewEmployer}"`, which errors.

I'm trying to get this in as little code-behind as possible, none preferably.

Comment: ButtonBaseExtensions.Command seems to be an attached property. Why don't you change is to handle DoubleClick on any element (and not only button) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use something like Marlon Grech's [attached command behaviors](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/).